# Pulling a report from a public Crystal Report server using .Net

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

What is the best method for pulling a report from a Crystal Report Server that is public facing.  I only have public access to the server but need to pull a report form it on a daily basis.  You log on [here](http://crystal11.brevardclerk.us/InfoViewApp/logon.aspx) with the user id of public and no password.  In the past, I've screen scraped sites for the info I needed.  The report server here makes this very complicated from what I've seen in Fiddler.

Does Crystal (or the report server):
1. Expose a simple web service?
2. Is the a client library I can lean on?

Any help would be appreicated.  My ultimate goal is to pull down the report using .Net and then pull out the contents of the report for a database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the [BusinessObjects SDK](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/devlib.htm#en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_dotNet_doc/doc/boesdk_net_doc/html/Introduction.html)?  You should be able to connect to the repository if you can authenticate as a guest.  From there, it's pretty easy to get the RPT files.

Comment: Is the SDK Free or are licensing fees involved?  Where do I get a copy.  Which version is applicable for the Rpoert Server I am working against?  Thanks!